# Inject @SessionScoped value into filter with Guice

Tags: guice, guice-servlet, sitebricks

I have a class hold value of a user in session

```
 @SessionScoped
 class UserSession{}
```

Now I have a `LoginFilter` to ensure some url accessed with user login

```
class LoginFilter{
   @Inject UserSession userSession;
   ...
}
```

Then Out of scope exception was thrown when I try to  bootstrap jetty. How can I check if the session contains the `UserSession` object? I don't know the attribute name of `UserSession` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject a `Provider<UserSession>` instead of a plain `UserSession`.